# SVG Icons with <use> :hover not working in Chrome with external loading

Tags: html, css, svg, hover

**To be very, very clear:**

If you copy-paste this code, it will work in a Chrome browser. The issue lies when you put a map.svg containing the nested `<symbol>`'s and access the resource with external loading like so:

```
<svg role="img" title="Python" class="icon">
    <use xlink:href="public/img/map.svg#python" />
</svg>
```

**Here's the code that's in a `<section>`**

```
<div class="row">
  <svg role="img" title="Python" class="icon col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"><use xlink:href="#python" /></svg>
  <svg role="img" title="C" class="icon col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"><use xlink:href="#c" /></svg>
  <svg role="img" title="C++" class="icon col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"><use xlink:href="#cpp" /></svg>
  <svg role="img" title="Swift" class="icon col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"><use xlink:href="#swift" /></svg>
</div>
```

If you notice, I'm referencing an SVG map file with `<symbol id="relevant-id">` for each SVG path. I was able to get

```
.icon:hover {
  fill: red;
}
```

working as you would expect in Chrome, but I had the SVG map referenced at the bottom of index.html instead of in a separate directory. So, when working to solve this problem, please be certain to make sure your **xlink:href** points to the correct location.

**Here's the SVG map:**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display:none;">
    <symbol id="c" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
        <title>C</title>
        <path d="M639 579.3c-5.5-3.2-11.1-6.4-16.7-9.6-4.5-2.5-5.8-2.1-8.4 2-14.3 22.2-32.7 39.8-57 50.6-17 7.5-34.9 10.7-53.4 11-20.6.3-40.5-3.4-59-12.4-23-11.1-40.6-28.4-54.5-49.4-.7-1-.9-2.4-1.5-3.6-.7-1.5-1.4-3.1-2.2-4.6-2.9-5.2-6.4-10.1-8.5-15.7-8.1-21.3-9.9-43.4-6.8-65.9 4.3-31.2 17.8-58 41.1-79.3 32.4-29.5 71-39.6 114-33 35.3 5.4 63 23.4 83.3 52.8 2.4 3.5 4.7 7.2 7.1 10.9 39.1-22.6 78-45.2 117.1-67.8-2.7-3.6-5.2-7-7.7-10.4-13.3-18.9-27.9-36.3-44.7-52.1-30.9-29-66.6-49.8-107.8-60.5-39.3-10.2-78.8-10.6-118.6-4-54.1 8.9-100.4 33.4-139.3 71.9-31.5 31.2-53.9 68.2-67.5 110.4-10.7 33.6-14.6 68.2-11.2 103.3 2.1 23 7.4 45.4 15.3 67.1 5.5 15.2 11.4 30.3 19.9 44.1 18 29.2 40.3 54.9 67.4 76.1 43.9 34.3 93.8 52.7 149.3 55.6 33.1 1.7 65.6-2.6 97.1-13 56-18.5 101.6-51.3 135.2-100.1 4.2-6.1 7.9-12.6 12-19.1-1.9-1.5-3.4-3.1-5.1-4.1-30.1-17-59.5-34.1-88.9-51.2z"/><path d="M899.6 0H100.4C45 0 0 45 0 100.4v799.2C0 955 45 1000 100.4 1000h799.2c55.4 0 100.4-45 100.4-100.4V100.4C1000 45 955 0 899.6 0zM918 691.4c0 11.9-2.1 23.5-6.7 34.5-8.1 19.3-22.2 33.2-40 43.6-97.7 56.6-195.4 113.2-293.2 169.7-12.9 7.4-25.8 14.8-39.1 21.4-14.6 7.2-30.1 9.6-46.4 7.8-14.6-1.6-27.9-6.8-40.5-14.1C378.1 911.5 304 868.9 230 826c-35.2-20.5-70.7-40.8-105.4-62-25.7-15.7-38.6-39.5-38.8-69.8-.1-15.7-.1-31.3-.1-46.9 0-.9-.3-1.8-.4-2.7V313.5c.1-1.1.4-2.2.4-3.2-.1-7.7.2-15.5 1.9-23.1 5-22 17.7-38.7 36.4-50.6 13.9-8.8 28.1-17 42.3-25.2 56.7-32.7 113.6-65.4 170.4-98.1 41-23.5 81.7-47.3 122.9-70.5 25.8-14.6 52.6-15.7 79.4-2.9 11.2 5.3 22 11.8 32.8 18.1 58.5 33.7 117.1 67.7 175.6 101.5 40.6 23.5 81.1 47 121.6 70.6 9.8 5.7 19.2 12.2 26.9 20.8 15.4 16.8 22 36.9 22 59.3.1 126.9.1 254.1.1 381.2z"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="cpp" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
        <title>C++</title>
        <path d="M639 579.3c-5.5-3.2-11.1-6.4-16.7-9.6-4.5-2.5-5.8-2.1-8.4 2-14.3 22.2-32.7 39.8-57 50.6-17 7.5-34.9 10.7-53.4 11-20.6.3-40.5-3.4-59-12.4-23-11.1-40.6-28.4-54.5-49.4-.7-1-.9-2.4-1.5-3.6-.7-1.5-1.4-3.1-2.2-4.6-2.9-5.2-6.4-10.1-8.5-15.7-8.1-21.3-9.9-43.4-6.8-65.9 4.3-31.2 17.8-58 41.1-79.3 32.4-29.5 71-39.6 114-33 35.3 5.4 63 23.4 83.3 52.8 2.4 3.5 4.7 7.2 7.1 10.9 39.1-22.6 78-45.2 117.1-67.8-2.7-3.6-5.2-7-7.7-10.4-13.3-18.9-27.9-36.3-44.7-52.1-30.9-29-66.6-49.8-107.8-60.5-39.3-10.2-78.8-10.6-118.6-4-54.1 8.9-100.4 33.4-139.3 71.9-31.5 31.2-53.9 68.2-67.5 110.4-10.7 33.6-14.6 68.2-11.2 103.3 2.1 23 7.4 45.4 15.3 67.1 5.5 15.2 11.4 30.3 19.9 44.1 18 29.2 40.3 54.9 67.4 76.1 43.9 34.3 93.8 52.7 149.3 55.6 33.1 1.7 65.6-2.6 97.1-13 56-18.5 101.6-51.3 135.2-100.1 4.2-6.1 7.9-12.6 12-19.1-1.9-1.5-3.4-3.1-5.1-4.1-30.1-17-59.5-34.1-88.9-51.2z"/><path d="M736.5 453h-30.4v32.4h-32.4v30.2h32.5V548h30.4v-32.3h32.2v-30.2h-32.3V453z"/><path d="M899.6 0H100.4C45 0 0 45 0 100.4v799.2C0 955 45 1000 100.4 1000h799.2c55.4 0 100.4-45 100.4-100.4V100.4C1000 45 955 0 899.6 0zM918 691.4c0 11.9-2.1 23.5-6.7 34.5-8.1 19.3-22.2 33.2-40 43.6-97.7 56.6-195.4 113.2-293.2 169.7-12.9 7.4-25.8 14.8-39.1 21.4-14.6 7.2-30.1 9.6-46.4 7.8-14.6-1.6-27.9-6.8-40.5-14.1C378.1 911.5 304 868.9 230 826c-35.2-20.5-70.7-40.8-105.4-62-25.7-15.7-38.6-39.5-38.8-69.8-.1-15.7-.1-31.3-.1-46.9 0-.9-.3-1.8-.4-2.7V313.5c.1-1.1.4-2.2.4-3.2-.1-7.7.2-15.5 1.9-23.1 5-22 17.7-38.7 36.4-50.6 13.9-8.8 28.1-17 42.3-25.2 56.7-32.7 113.6-65.4 170.4-98.1 41-23.5 81.7-47.3 122.9-70.5 25.8-14.6 52.6-15.7 79.4-2.9 11.2 5.3 22 11.8 32.8 18.1 58.5 33.7 117.1 67.7 175.6 101.5 40.6 23.5 81.1 47 121.6 70.6 9.8 5.7 19.2 12.2 26.9 20.8 15.4 16.8 22 36.9 22 59.3.1 126.9.1 254.1.1 381.2z"/><path d="M849.9 453.1h-30.1v32.4h-32.4v30.1h32.5V548h30.2v-32.4h32.4v-30.3H850c-.1-10.9-.1-21.5-.1-32.2z"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="python" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
        <title>Python</title>
        <path d="M619 858.9c20.7 0 37.3-16.7 37.3-37.2 0-20.5-16.8-37.1-37.2-37.1-20.6 0-37.1 16.6-37.1 37.1-.1 20.7 16.4 37.2 37 37.2zM384.8 140.4c-20.8 0-37.3 16.5-37.3 37.1s16.6 37.2 37.1 37.2c20.6 0 37.2-16.6 37.3-37 .1-20.6-16.5-37.3-37.1-37.3z"/><path d="M899.6 0H100.4C45 0 0 45 0 100.4v799.2C0 955 45 1000 100.4 1000h799.2c55.4 0 100.4-45 100.4-100.4V100.4C1000 45 955 0 899.6 0zM268.3 607.5c-.3 33.2-.1 66.5 0 99.8 0 1.9-.4 2.3-2.3 2.3-23.1-.1-46.1-.1-69.2 0-13.2.1-25.6-2.9-37.4-8.3-19.7-8.9-34.8-23.1-46.9-40.8-12.9-18.9-21-39.9-26.7-61.9-7.9-31-10.6-62.7-11-94.6v-10.2c0-3.6.1-7.2.3-10.8.5-17.2 2-34.2 4.8-51.2 3.1-18.7 7.9-36.9 15.4-54.4 8.8-20.8 20.8-39.4 38.1-54.1 18.1-15.5 38.9-24.5 62.4-27.4 7.5-.9 15-.5 22.5-.4 19.8.1 39.6 0 59.3 0H500c2 0 2.7-.5 2.6-2.6-.1-8 0-16.1-.1-24 0-3.1.3-2.7-2.7-2.7H298c-1.9 0-2.5-.4-2.5-2.4v-55.7c0-12.9.1-25.7-.1-38.5-.1-5.1.1-10.1 1.3-15.2 3.4-14.4 11.4-25.9 22.3-35.6 11.6-10.5 25.3-17.9 39.9-23.6 21.8-8.5 44.5-13.3 67.6-16.3 21-2.7 42.1-3.8 63.2-4.2h19.6c8.8.4 17.7.7 26.5 1.1 7.7.4 15.4 1.3 23 2.1 4 .4 8 .8 11.9 1.4 5.6.8 11.2 1.8 16.9 2.9 9.8 1.9 19.5 4 29 6.9 9.6 2.9 19.1 6.3 28.2 10.5 13 6.1 25 13.6 35.4 23.3 12.3 11.4 21.2 25.2 25.5 41.7 2.2 8.3 2.2 16.8 2.1 25.3-.2 61.1-.1 122.4-.1 183.5 0 9.8-.6 19.7-2.6 29.4-5.4 27-19.1 48.6-42.4 63.6-21.6 13.9-45.6 20.2-71 20.3-67.5.3-135 .1-202.5.1-12.8 0-25.3.9-37.8 3.9-25.7 6.2-46.7 19.5-61.4 41.7-15 22.8-21.5 48.1-21.7 75.1zm657.4-51.1c-.1.5-.3.9-.4 1.4-1.5 11.1-3.6 22.2-6.4 33.1-6.1 23.6-15.2 45.9-30 65.4-19.4 25.4-44.7 41.2-76.3 46.4-8.3 1.4-16.7 1.1-25 1.1-55.5-.2-111-.1-166.6-.1-39.1 0-78.1 0-117.2-.1-2.2 0-2.7.6-2.7 2.7.1 7.8.1 15.6.1 23.4 0 3.2 0 3.2 3.3 3.2 67 0 134 0 201-.1 2 0 2.6.5 2.6 2.5-.1 8.5.1 17.2.1 25.7.1 24.1.2 48.2.2 72.3 0 2.8-.2 5.6-.7 8.4-2.5 13.3-9 24.3-18.3 33.9-11.8 12.3-26.4 20.7-42.1 27.1-25.5 10.4-52.2 15.4-79.4 18.4-13.8 1.5-27.5 2.3-41.4 2.7-24.1.7-48.2.3-72.2-1.8-10.6-.9-21.3-2.2-31.8-4-14.1-2.4-27.9-5.6-41.5-10.1-19.4-6.4-37.7-15-53.3-28.3-14.8-12.6-25.4-27.7-30-46.8-2-8.1-1.8-16.4-1.7-24.7.2-60.9.1-122 .1-182.9 0-10.8.7-21.5 3.1-32.1 6.5-28.9 22.6-50.7 48.7-64.9 20.1-10.9 41.8-16.2 64.5-16.3 67.8-.2 135.5-.1 203.3-.1 13.5 0 26.7-1.3 39.8-4.8 21.3-5.7 39.4-16.6 53.2-33.9 18.2-22.9 26.3-49.6 26.9-78.4.7-34.3.2-68.7.1-102.9 0-2.1.5-2.6 2.6-2.6 23.1.1 46.2.1 69.4 0 11.7 0 22.9 2.5 33.7 6.9 19.8 8.1 35.2 21.7 47.8 38.8 11.3 15.5 18.8 32.8 24.9 50.9 4.5 13.6 7.5 27.6 9.8 41.8.7 4.4 1.4 8.7 2.1 13.2-.3 38.7-.3 77.2-.3 115.6z"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="swift" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
        <title>Swift</title>
        <path d="M499 487.2h.3c-.1-.1-.2-.1-.2-.2-.1 0-.1.1-.1.2z"/><path d="M899.6 0H100.4C45 0 0 45 0 100.4v799.2C0 955 45 1000 100.4 1000h799.2c55.4 0 100.4-45 100.4-100.4V100.4C1000 45 955 0 899.6 0zm20.8 854c-.7 5.2-1.6 10.4-3.8 15.3-.9 1.9-1.7 4.3-4.1 4.4-2.4.1-3-2.3-3.9-4-9.4-18-21.2-34-37.3-46.6-15.5-12-33-19-52.4-21.6-19.3-2.5-38.2-.5-57 3.7-16.1 3.6-31.6 8.9-46.6 15.6-6.7 2.9-13 6.8-19.5 10.1-22.4 11.1-45.7 19.5-70 25.4-16.6 4-33.2 7-50.2 8.8-20.4 2.1-40.8 2.7-61.2 1.9-26.8-1.1-53.3-4.6-79.5-10.3-40.8-8.8-79.8-22.7-117.4-40.6-39.5-18.8-76.2-42-110.4-69.2-14-11-27.3-22.8-40.3-35-6.3-5.9-12.6-12-18.5-18.3-26.7-28-50.5-58-71.2-90.7-.3-.5-.5-1-.8-1.5l.2-.2c10 8 20.3 15.6 31 22.6 16.3 10.5 33.1 19.8 50.4 28.6 9.2 4.7 18.7 9 28.1 13.3 7.6 3.4 15.4 6.4 23.2 9.4 9.5 3.7 19.3 7.1 29 10.2 10.7 3.4 21.7 6.4 32.6 9.1 9 2.2 18.1 4.1 27.1 5.9 5.6 1.1 11.2 2 17 2.6 4.9.5 9.7 1.7 14.6 2.1 3.5.3 7.1.6 10.6 1 4.9.5 9.9 1 14.9 1.1 9.6.2 19.4.7 29 .4 12.4-.3 24.9-1 37.2-2.4 13.8-1.6 27.4-3.9 41-7 32.8-7.6 63.8-19.8 92.6-37.1.7-.4 1.3-.8 2-1.2.2-.1.3-.3.6-.5-4-3.1-8-6.2-12-9.4-7.8-6.2-15.7-12.6-23.5-18.9-1.6-1.3-3.1-2.6-4.7-3.9-11.4-9.2-22.5-19-33.5-28.7-39.8-35.1-77.6-72.4-114-111-7.8-8.3-15.6-16.6-23.3-25-7.6-8.3-15.3-16.9-22.8-25.3-6-6.7-11.9-13.6-17.8-20.4-28.3-33-56-66.5-82.9-100.7-6.3-8-12.3-16.2-18.9-24-5.5-6.6-11.6-12.8-16.9-19.6-10.8-14-20.3-28.9-30-43.6-.1-.2-.1-.4-.2-.5 2 .9 3.4 2.6 4.9 4.1 34.4 31 70.2 60.5 106.4 89.4 38.7 30.7 78.1 60.5 118 89.6 9 6.6 18.2 13.2 27.4 19.6 5.3 3.8 10.6 7.6 16.1 11.3 12.8 8.6 25.6 17.2 38.5 25.8 9.5 6.3 19.2 12.3 29 18.2.5.3.9.9 1.6.6-3.5-3.9-7-7.7-10.6-11.5-15.1-16.2-29.7-32.6-44.3-49.4-27-31.1-53.2-63-78.7-95.4-35.7-45.6-70.5-91.9-103.2-139.8-1-1.5-1.9-3-2.8-4.5l.3-.3c2.9 2.9 5.9 5.7 8.8 8.6 33.8 33.7 68.6 66.6 104.3 98.4 36.5 32.5 73.9 64.1 112.2 94.5 22.3 17.7 44.8 34.8 67.6 51.9 12.4 9.4 25.2 18.6 37.9 27.6 9.6 6.8 19.4 13.7 29.2 20.3 17 11.3 33.9 22.6 51.5 33 1.1.7 1.4.6 1.9-.6 7.3-19 12.8-38.5 16.5-58.4 1.8-9.7 3.2-19.5 4.1-29.3 1.7-18.2 2.1-36.3 1.1-54.5-3.7-68.7-24.2-132.5-56-193.1-12.1-23.2-26-45.3-41.4-66.5-.4-.5-.7-1-1.2-1.7.9-.2 1.4.4 1.9.7 36.6 22.5 70.5 48.5 101.5 78.2 50 48 90.8 102.7 120.8 165.4 5.5 11.4 10.6 23.1 15.1 35 2.9 7.9 5.7 15.9 8.4 23.8 6 17.8 10.6 35.9 14.2 54.4 3.1 16.3 5.2 32.7 6.3 49.3 1.1 16.8 1.1 33.4-.1 50.2-1.1 15.4-3.2 30.5-6.5 45.6-.6 2.5-.8 5.2-2.1 7.5 0 2.9-1 5.5-1.8 8.2-1.1 4.1-1.8 8.3-3.5 12.2-.3.8.1 1.1.5 1.6 24.4 30.2 43.3 63.6 55.8 100.3 6.6 19.5 11.2 39.6 13.6 60 1.8 15.3 2.3 30.4.3 45.4z"/>
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

**CSS you'd need to get it working:**

Bootstrap 3.3.7 CDN: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css

```
.icon {
  fill: black;
}
```

Lastly, here's a CodePen:
https://codepen.io/kylemh/pen/ZeBKYG

**TO REITERATE, THE CODEPEN WORKS BECAUSE THE SVG MAP IS IN INDEX.HTML**

Answer (score -1):

I checked it out in Chrome on Mac and didn't see any strange behavior.

Are you certain that you don't have any extensions interfering?

[image]

Comment: I tried making it clear that the issue doesn't occur in CodePen, but it does occur on a live site where the SVG map is in a seperate directory and not located within index.html - this is important because I'd like to cache the SVGs.

Comment: This seems more of a comment than an answer. Answers typically are not places to ask followup questions. You should probably avoid questions that you wish to say this kind of thing on till you can comment.